# Why does CELL("Width", A1) fill the cell to the right with "FALSE"?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to check the combined widths of each column on various sheets with the intent of making the total print area widths match across all sheets in the workbook.  When I enter `=CELL("Width", A1)` into a cell I get the width in points (rounded, but good enough for what I'm doing), but then it also fills the next cell to the right with "FALSE".  This is annoying, since I would like to be able to simply drag the formula across all the columns that I want to check and then sum them.  I know how to work around the issue so I can drag it vertically instead, but just wondering if there is a way to alter this behavior so I don't have to?

Also - bonus points if anyone can tell me what the secondary cell is there for in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf) is helpful here:

> "width": Returns an array with 2 items.
>
> The 1st item in the array is the column width of the cell, rounded off to an integer. Each unit of column width is equal to the width of one character in the default font size.
>
> The 2nd item in the array is a Boolean value, the value is TRUE if the column width is the default or FALSE if the width has been explicitly set by the user.

If you only want the 1st item in the array, you can use INDEX:

```
=INDEX(CELL("width",A1),1)
```

If by "secondary cell" you mean the one to the right with FALSE, you are seeing Excel's new [spill functionality](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dynamic-arrays-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531).

> Excel formulas that return multiple values, also known as an array, return results to neighboring cells. This behavior is called **spilling**.

Based on your version of Excel, you're seeing the full array result of CELL.

**EDIT:**
A better way to do this is to use the [implicit intersection operator](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34) `@` to return the first value of the array:

```
=@CELL("width",A1)
```

Comment: Now ^^^^^THAT ^^^^^ is how one should quote and reference a link.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks. I have to admit, I never knew that width returned an array. Kinda cool.